# why I get error on current route name with id

Tags: laravel

in my app I use link as language switcher, it works ok in all web routing and show the correct button for language switch but, in my product page with id I get this error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: products] [URI: {lang}/products/{id}]
```

this is the app web route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function () {
  Route::get('products/{id}', 'AppController@products')->name('products');
});
```

this is the controller:

```
public function products($lang, $id){
$products = Category::with('products')->where('id', $id)->get();
return view('products', compact('products', 'lang'));}
```

and this is the buttons I use for language switch:

```
@if(app()->isLocale('fa'))
      <div id="change"><a href="{{ Route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}">English</a></div>
  @elseif(app()->isLocale('en'))
      <div id="change"><a href="{{ Route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), 'fa') }}">Farsi</a></div>
  @endif
```

AS I said the language switch work ok in all routes except in product with :id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The products route you've defined requires an ID and you are not putting one in the route generator.

Your code is a bit confusing, so what I think you are doing is this:

You are displaying a list of products in a category of `$id`, with one single link to switch languages. You will need to update your route to include a the single common product id:

```
public function products($lang, $id){
    $products = Category::with('products')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $product_id = $id;
    return view('products', compact('products', 'product_id', 'lang'));
}
```

Then the output:

```
@if(app()->isLocale('fa'))
    <div id="change"><a href="{{ Route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'en', 'id' => $product_id) }}">English</a></div>
@elseif(app()->isLocale('en'))
  <div id="change"><a href="{{ Route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'fa', 'id' => $product_id) }}">Farsi</a></div>
@endif
```

Should work for you.

Comment: very tkx, yes this worked ! I have seen many have problem in laravel language switch, this solution may be a general guid.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parameter in your products route. Only parameter you defined is `id`, but your controller expects `lang` as well, which you don't pass. Change your route definition to:

```
Route::get('products/{lang}/{id}', 'AppController@products')->name('products');
```

Also, remove curly brackets from your route prefix, since this is only the name of the route, and shouldn't be defined as a parameter:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'lang'], function ()
```

Comment: Yes you did, but `{lang}` represents the custom name for the route, not a parameter. If you do `php artisan route:list` , you will see that your route doesn't have `{lang}` parameter.

Comment: tkx but if I remove {lang} all other routes doesn't work and route:list show:  lang/products/{lang}/{id}

Comment: Also this is my link to product : <a href="{{ route('products', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => $category->id]) }}" class=""></a>

Comment: What do you mean they don't work. Did you get any exceptions?

Comment: your try although didn't work for me but appreciated.